# Airflow - creating a months worth of backfills in the Airflow UI for a DAG that runs daily

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG that runs daily starting from 3/3/2022, but i need to backfill for 1/1 - 3/2. I know I can add a new DAG run in the UI by going to Browse -> DAG runs and adding in a run for each day but that would take a long time to create for ~60 days, is there a faster way to do this in the UI specifically since I haven't had much luck getting this to work in the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Airflow CLI to run the `backfill` command

```
airflow dags backfill <dag_id> --start-date START_DATE --end-date END_DATE
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#backfill